# VBA Copy to clipboard shows garbage characters

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I have a small VBA that makes summary of insertion and deletions on Word document; The summary is showed on a form text box and also have a copy button that copies the button.Text into a string variable called sTemp.

The code for the Copy button is this:

```
Private Sub btnCopyClip_Click()
Dim myData As DataObject

If sTemp = "" Then
End
Else
End If
Set myData = New DataObject
myData.SetText sTemp
myData.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

but when I try to paste into word or Excel only shows "??" in the pasted cell (the behavior is the same for Excel or Word) as you can see here:

[image]

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: `DataObject` hasn't been reliable for a while now, in my experience.  If you need to copy text to the clipboard in Windows then the API approach is much more robust.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/send-information-to-the-clipboard

Comment: Yes, this soluction works perfectly. Thanks.